# OAuth 2.0 authorization in PHP with user credentials

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, access-token

Cheers,

I'm currently fighting with a REST API and OAuth 2.0 authorization with a PHP client. Unfortunately I don't know how to get the access token with PHP.

I was able to connect to the API and recieve the access token with Postman. Here are the authorization settings to get it working:

```
Type: OAuth 2.0
Add authorization data to: Request Headers
Token Name: MyToken
Grant Type: Password Credentials
Access Token URL: https://thisisaniceurl.com/oauth/token
Username: myusername
Password: P@ssword123
Client ID: ThisIsAClientId
Client Secret: 123456789-987654321-1234
Scope: <empty>
Client Authentication: Send as Basic Auth header
```

How do I put this request into PHP? This is what I have:

```
$AccessTokenUrl = "https://thisisaniceurl.com/oauth/token";
$Username = "myusername";
$Password = "P@ssword123";
$ClientId = "ThisIsAClientId";
$ClientSecret = "123456789-987654321-1234";

$provider = new OAuth([
    'clientId'                => $ClientId ,
    'clientSecret'            => $ClientSecret,
    'urlAccessToken'          => $AccessTokenUrl,
]);

$accessToken = $provider->getAccessToken($AccessTokenUrl, [
    'username' => $Username,
    'password' => $Password
    ]);

var_dump($accessToken);
```

Unfortunately it only returns "NULL". What am I doing wrong?

Thank you. :-)

Comment: What library are you using? It should return some error message. Btw, why would you need to pass username and password to a OAuth server?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson: I'm using this one: http://pecl.php.net/package/oauth. It doesn't return any error messages even with `error_reporting(-1);`. We have a web based software in our company that needs a new feature which can't be implemented in the software itself. But our users should be able to use this new "external" feature with the same credentials.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/oauth.getaccesstoken.php wants the API endpoint URL as first parameter - you passed `password` instead. But from the description of that method, it doesn’t look like that would take username & password as parameters in the first place. And as @Magnus said, why would you pass those in an OAuth context in the first place?

Comment: Thank you, I corrected the parameter of getAccessToken in my question above. Though it still returns NULL. :-( I take username and password because I didn't find another solution to get the access token with Postman. All other methods only returned "Full authentication is required to access this resource" from the server.

Comment: If I'm not reading something wrong, and I went to php.net docs page, this is what it states: `This extension provides OAuth 1.0a consumer and provider bindings`. Note the **1.0a**. And then note **2.0** in your question. I haven't used OAuth 1.x before, but looking at the parameters you're using and passing - where's the `grant_type`? Where are scopes? Which OAuth version are you supposed to implement?

Comment: Just as @Mjh noted, that extension is for Oauth 1.0a and not 2.0. You need to use a 2.0 client. There are plenty of oauth2 libraries out there, like [league/oauth2-client](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client)

Comment: @Mjh: Thank you. Questioning the version made me think again. Now I found a new example right here https://developer.byu.edu/docs/consume-api/use-api/oauth-20/oauth-20-php-sample-code (Section: Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant Type). This one works fine for me.